# Modify the main loop to display current month / year

Tags: loop, pre-get-posts

So `pre_get_posts` seems to be the way to do this now - a lot of the background is nicely explained here: [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

I can happily modify the main loop to show a chosen month using this function:

```
function loop_current_month( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'monthnum', 3 );
    return;
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'loop_current_month' );
```

However, I would like to modify the loop for the current month, and the current year.

How can `$query->set()` take two vars? Something like:

```
$query->set( 'monthnum', 3 & 'year', 2013 );
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried adding a second $query->set() ?

```
function loop_current_month( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'monthnum', date('m') );
        $query->set( 'year', date("Y") );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'loop_current_month' );
```

This should get all the posts from the current month or this year, note date('m') and date('Y')

Comment: That'll do it - thanks! Thanks also for the date function tip, I was going to do that outside of the loop function, then add the variables, but putting it straight it makes much more sense :) Cheers.